# Error on creating database in android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create SQLite database in android studio but I got the error below, I am beginner for android studio and it took me really a long time to find a solution.

The error is:

```
    E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "_ItemName": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: iq.nazaha.wissam.CoiApp, PID: 3786
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{iq.nazaha.wissam.CoiApp/iq.nazaha.wissam.CoiApp.AddNewItemPage}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "_ItemName": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE items(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY _ItemName TEXT _ItemLocation TEXT _ItemPerson TEXT );
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "_ItemName": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE items(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY _ItemName TEXT _ItemLocation TEXT _ItemPerson TEXT );
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
                      at iq.nazaha.wissam.CoiApp.AppDB.onCreate(AppDB.java:32)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                      at iq.nazaha.wissam.CoiApp.AppDB.dbToString(AppDB.java:65)
                      at iq.nazaha.wissam.CoiApp.AddNewItemPage.printDB(AddNewItemPage.java:52)
                      at iq.nazaha.wissam.CoiApp.AddNewItemPage.onCreate(AddNewItemPage.java:32)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

And my DB handler code is:

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;


public class AppDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "items.db";
    private static final String TABLE_ITEMSINFO = "items";
    public static final String  COLUMN_ITEMID = "_id";
    public static final String  COLUMN_ITEMNAME = "_ItemName";
    public static final String  COLUMN_ITEMLOCATION = "_ItemLocation";
    public static final String  COLUMN_ITEMPERSON = "_ItemPerson";

    public AppDB(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMSINFO + "(" +
                COLUMN_ITEMID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY " +
                COLUMN_ITEMNAME + " TEXT " +
                COLUMN_ITEMLOCATION + " TEXT " +
                COLUMN_ITEMPERSON + " TEXT " +
                "); ";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_ITEMSINFO);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // Add to the database
    public void AddItems(ItemsInfo itemsinfo){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_ITEMID, itemsinfo.get_id());
        values.put(COLUMN_ITEMNAME, itemsinfo.get_ItemName());
        values.put(COLUMN_ITEMLOCATION, itemsinfo.get_ItemLocation());
        values.put(COLUMN_ITEMPERSON, itemsinfo.get_ItemPerson());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_ITEMSINFO, null, values);
        db.close();

    }

    // Delete from the database
    public void DeleteItems(String ItemId){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(" DELETE FROM " + TABLE_ITEMSINFO + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ITEMID + "=\"" + ItemId + "\";" );
        db.close();

    }

    // Print the database
    public String dbToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMSINFO + " WHERE 1";

        //CURSOR point to a location tn the database
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()){
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("itemname"))!= null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("itemname"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're missing **commas** between your fields definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [a `CREATE TABLE` statement](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), the columns are separated by columns.

Replace:

```
String query = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMSINFO + "(" +
            COLUMN_ITEMID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY " +
            COLUMN_ITEMNAME + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_ITEMLOCATION + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_ITEMPERSON + " TEXT " +
            "); ";
```

with:

```
String query = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMSINFO + "(" +
            COLUMN_ITEMID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COLUMN_ITEMNAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_ITEMLOCATION + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_ITEMPERSON + " TEXT " +
            "); ";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works right now. However, I'v got another error with the Cursor :) but I'll try to solve it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add `commas` to your SQL query

```
String query = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMSINFO + "(" +
            COLUMN_ITEMID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COLUMN_ITEMNAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_ITEMLOCATION + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_ITEMPERSON + " TEXT " +
            "); ";

db.execSQL(query);
```